WCS How do I get the Woocommerce Subscription Object Given a Subscription ID
I'm trying to do something that I thought would be really easy -- get the WCS subscription object by passing the subscription ID.
I have a valid subscription ID. One that I can bring up in the admin area and edit. I can also retrieve the post object via get_post() and also get the post type via get_post_type(). The post type is shop_subscription.
However, when I try to get the subscription object via wcs_get_subscription() it returns FALSE.
Here's my code that I've tried:
$subscription_id = 50543;  //Valid subscription id which can be seen in WC Subscriptions

$post_type = get_post_type( $subscription_id); // Returns a post type of "shop_subscription"

$post = get_post( $subscription_id); // Returns the post object

$subscription = wcs_get_subscription( $subscription_id); // RETURNS FALSE -- FAILS TO GET THE SUBSCRIPTION OBJECT

Looking at the definition for wcs_get_subscription() from WCS it seems pretty straight-forward, though I'm not familiar with the order_factory method.  Still, it seems that wcs_get_subscription() should do just that - return the subscription object.
function wcs_get_subscription( $the_subscription ) {

    if ( is_object( $the_subscription ) && wcs_is_subscription( $the_subscription ) ) {
        $the_subscription = $the_subscription->get_id();
    }

    $subscription = WC()->order_factory->get_order( $the_subscription );

    if ( ! wcs_is_subscription( $subscription ) ) {
        $subscription = false;
    }

    return apply_filters( 'wcs_get_subscription', $subscription );
}

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?
